# How can I get Ogone payment transaction feedback through POST variables

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

I'm currently building a PHP website which is integrating Ogone API to perform online payment.

At the moment, I have implemented my hidden form containing all the information needed to be sent to the Ogone transaction URL. **Once the access is granted and the payment has been authorized, my page is being automatically redirected to another page**, as it's supposed to behave.

However **I'd like to display on the redirected page some information about the payment itself**, as reference number, amount, ... I know there is a way for Ogone to send me that as a transaction feedback once the payment has been performed, but I can't find the way.
What I've managed to do so far is retrieve the information passed to the URL, but I don't want that huge URL appearing on the website, this is why I'd like to get those in a POST request.

I've played a bit with the **"Direct HTTP server-to-server request " option in the Configuration > Technical Information > Transaction Feedback** section, but this hasn't given anything so far. The callback is successfully called but nothing is in the POST when I look it up with this:

```
file_put_contents( 'debug' . time() . '.log', var_export( $_POST, true));
```

Any idea about something I might have forgotten?

Comment: can u share with me, how u had done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up activating the "Transaction feedback" parameter, in this panel the first checkbox is allowing payment information to be returned to the redirected page. Whether the Accept/Decline/Cancel/Exception redirection is being triggered doesn't matter, I get the same result anyway.

- One of the problem was that I'm not getting anything in the $_POST back, but I found out that the $_REQUEST variable was containing the information I needed, so that's fine for me.
- The last issue was that this checkbox also returns everything in GET so it appears in the URL.
  That's not really a security issue since there is a SHA signature in the parameters to make sure nothing has been altered. This was mainly to avoid a huge URL appearing for the user, so I guess i'll just make a manual redirection once I got what I need from the $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the page I used I was checking the GET and POST values. I am not very familiar with PHP, Could you be getting it back as $_GET and not $_POST.

Comment: There is a way to retrieve payment feedback if activated in the Ogone interface, but this is GET only. I implemented a workaround so I'm gonna write a new answer about it.